# Extract domain from a string using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I have an string which include many website url but i want to extract the only url that is out side  these bracket [ ].

Can someone correct this ?

Note : Output Must be www.google.com and it not necessary that domain name outside [  ] will come at the end of string.

```js
var str = '[[www.abc.com/corporate/partner/just-a-test]]acdascvdvsa.1563e24e32e42|[[www.abc.com/corporate/partner/just-a-test]]1563e24e32e42.1563e24e32e42|[[www.abc.com/instruments/infrared-guided-measurement/]]www.google.com&1566805689640.1566806059701.3';

// String can include https and instead of .com there can be .in 


var arr = str.split("|");

function domainName(str) {
  var match = str.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:w{3}\.)?([a-z\d\.-]+)\.(?:[a-z\.]{2,10})(?:[\w\.-]*)*/);
  if (match != null && match.length > 0) {
    return match;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
var domainname = domainName(str);
var domain = domainname;
console.log(domain);
```

Comment: dude did you want only "www.google.com&1566805689640.1566806059701.3"

Comment: Only www.google.com regardless of its position and the domain can be start with htttps and can have .in instead of .com at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CertainPerformance Suggest you can exclude the url that is in [ ] using replace then by using regex you can extract the domain name. Below is the code :

```js
var str = '[[www.abc.com/corporate/partner/just-a-test]]acdascvdvsa.1563e24e32e42|[[www.abc.com/corporate/partner/just-a-test]]1563e24e32e42.1563e24e32e42|[[www.abc.com/instruments/infrared-guided-measurement/]]www.google.com&1566805689640.1566806059701.3';

var str = str.replace(/\[\[[^[\]]*\]\]/g, '');

var ptrn = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:w{3}\.)?([a-z\d\.-]+)\.(?:[a-z\.]{2,10})(?:[\w\.-]*)*/g;

var i, value, domain, len, array;

array = str.split("|");

len = array.length;

for(i=0; len > i; i++) {

  value = array[i].match(ptrn);

  if (value !== null) {
    domain = value;
  }
 
  else {
     domain = "Not Found";
  }

}
 

document.write("Domain is = ", domain);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace all occurrences of `[[`, followed by non-brackets, followed by `]]` with a space::

```js
var str = '[[www.abc.com/corporate/partner/just-a-test]]acdascvdvsa.1563e24e32e42|[[www.abc.com/corporate/partner/just-a-test]]1563e24e32e42.1563e24e32e42|[[www.abc.com/instruments/infrared-guided-measurement/]]www.google.com&1566805689640.1566806059701.3';

const result = str.replace(/\[\[[^[\]]*\]\]/g, ' ');
console.log(result);
```

Then you can search for URLs in the replaced string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer CertainPerformance! Your Answer is some what useful :)

Answer (score 1):

this can be achieve by split

```js
var str = '[[www.abc.com/corporate/partner/just-a-test]]acdascvdvsa.1563e24e32e42|[[www.abc.com/corporate/partner/just-a-test]]1563e24e32e42.1563e24e32e42|[[www.abc.com/instruments/infrared-guided-measurement/]]www.google.com&1566805689640.1566806059701.3';
let ans=str.split("]")[6]
let finalAns=ans.split("&")[0]
console.log(finalAns)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer akshay! But its not the desire output, i have edited the question please check that.

Comment: its the right answer, if i have string which include the url every time at the same place , but that not going to happened url can be at different position and i just want to write code only once to get the url regardless of its position, so i [6] will not give the correct output if string going to change. code must be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Two main steps:

- Create a regular expression that matches your desired pattern.
- Use [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Example:

```js
// match all URLs
// let regex = /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)/g;

// match only the URL outside of the brackets
let regex = /(((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?))(([^[\]]+)(?:$|\[))/g;

function getUrlsFromText(input) {
  return input.match(regex);
}

console.log(getUrlsFromText('[[www.abc.com/corporate/partner/just-a-test]]acdascvdvsa.1563e24e32e42|[[www.abc.com/corporate/partner/just-a-test]]1563e24e32e42.1563e24e32e42|[[www.abc.com/instruments/infrared-guided-measurement/]]www.google.com&1566805689640.1566806059701.3'));
```

Note that I borrowed the URL matching part of the regular expression from [here](http://urlregex.com/). If you don't want the query string to be included (as it is on the google.com match), you can modify the regex as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer AndroidNoobie! But its not the desire output, i have edited the question please check that.

Comment: The process would be the same, you'd just use a different regex to match the desired pattern.

Comment: i know i need different regex see i also using regex but that not proving desire result.

Comment: Thanks Once again AndroidNoobie for your valuable time and answer. your answer is useful. But i just want to extract url till & so the correct output will be  www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

```
var dirtySource = "https://example.com/subdirectory";
var dirtyPos = dirtySource.indexOf("://"); // works for http and https
var cleanSource = dirtySource.substr(dirtyPos+3);
cleanSource = cleanSource.split("/")[0]; // trim off subdirectories
```

Comment: Please try explaining what you are proposing as the answer. It will help the users.

Comment: FWIW I did a Google search for "extract domain from a string" and this post came up. Nobody had a simple answer here so I had to code this myself.

Comment: If the title of the question is incorrect, then I'll remove my answer.

Comment: The title is misleading, I agree. The actual problem is not solved by your answer. And this post of yours came into the Low Quality Posts queue. Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers